# IOS customview removing the subviews

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to apply background Image to all my screens in my iOs application.

My initial screen is a Registration screen where i want to apply the background image, the registration screen is as shown below:

[image: Registration screen before applying background image]

I am using a custom `UIView` from `xib` file to apply the background image.

But after applying the background image it only shows the background image on the Registration screen and removes the login controls. I dont know why.

Following is the registration screen after applying the image background.

[image: Registration screen after applying image background]

One more thing, I can see the background image only on the run time not in the `Storyboard`.

Following is my implementation

I have created one `.xib` file having a simple `UIView`, this `UIView` would serve as a master view in all my application. To obtain the `UIView` from `nib` file and to apply further settings I am using a custom `UIView` class. In this custom `UIView` class I am applying the background image on the `UIView` obtained from the `nib` file. As you can see above I am applying this custom `UIView` class to the Registration screen `UIView`. Following is the code as shown below:

```
class BackgroundMap: UIView {
    var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        view = loadViewFromNib ()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "MapWantd")!)
        self.addSubview(view)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        view = loadViewFromNib ()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "MapWantd")!)
        self.addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() ->UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "BackgroundMap", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you apply the background image to the custom view itself without creating / adding a subview?

Comment: If you mean without using the command self.addSubview(view) in the customview class, in that case it shows the login controls but no background.

Comment: I have a doubt that on applying the customview it loses all the constraints attached to the login controls.

Comment: You could comment all lines which contain the `view` variable and change `view.backgroundColor = ...` to `self.backgroundColor = ...`. What happens when you try that?